# Regex alphanumeric with hyphen, single quotes, and single spacing is timing out (crashing)

Tags: regex, crash, struts

I have the following regular expression that I use but it crashes in my browsers (does nothing and then likely times out).

I am trying to accept alphanumeric, as well as dashes and single quotes. I'm also trying to restrict spacing to allow only single spaces (no more than one space consecutively)

```
<constant>
   <constant-name>expressionFormat</constant-name>
   <constant-value>^([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$</constant-value>
</constant>
```

A sample example string that crashes with this is:
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ43 5343443RSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ‘ –"

I'm using Struts. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  What output are you seeing?  Also, please add the `Struts` tag to your post so that only people who know what that is will click on it.

Comment: The page is simply not responsive. I imagine it has something to do wit the not allowing more than one space in a row. I do have a struts tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution.

My OLD expression:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$
```

First off, I got rid of the \s since it includes other things like tabs, new lines, etc, which I do not want.

The ? is "greedy", which means if the regex fails it continues evaluating the rest of the string until it's sure it's going to return a failure... In essence, the + and ? were making it try and check recursively making it resource intensive for longer strings.

The following expression works much better for my case:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9' -])*$
```

Comment: Very simple and easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the browser is just taking a really long time to process the regex search and may even be timing out.

Your sample string

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ43 5343443RSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ‘ –
```

will not be matched by your regular expression:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$
```

Add the special characters (‘ ’ — –), i.e.,

```
&lsquo; &rsquo; &mdash; &ndash;
```

if you want to accept them.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9'‘’—–-]+\s?)*$
```

This regex matches your sample string.

**UPDATE:**
Try this regex that uses atomic grouping to avoid catastrophic backtracking:

```
^(?>[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to add any more special characters (simple ' and - will do). How can I make an effective expression that does not time out??

Comment: ^(?>[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$ expression does not seem to work, testing it on regexpal.com